# RemotePost to iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm not really sure how to do this and if it's possible, but here goes.

I'm using RemotePost to send some parameters to a remote server, like this:

```
RemotePost post = new RemotePost { Url = "some url" };
post.Add("Name", name);
post.Add("UserId", userId);
post.Add("Ref", reference);
post.Add("Hash", hash);
post.Post();
```

It works. When i press on my "Send" button it sends the request but also opens the webpage in the current page that i'm viewing.

What i like to have is that the page opens inside of an iframe instead of reload my entire page with the new one.

I'm not really sure how to do this (if possible).

For example, can i simply create an iframe in my webpage:

```
<iframe name="myframe"></iframe>
```

Then use RemotePost something like this:

```
RemotePost post = new RemotePost { Url = "some url" };
post.Add("Name", name);
post.Add("UserId", userId);
post.Add("Ref", reference);
post.Add("Hash", hash);
post.Post("myframe");
```

Is this possible some how?